# How can Install CKFinder in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, ckeditor, ckfinder

I use `CKEditor` for my HTML Editor in project

How can install `CKFinder` in my project for select picture from that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following resources or make your question more detailed (i.e. explain which step is an issue):

- [CKFinder 2.x for ASP.NET installation instructions](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Installation)
- [CKFinder 2.x for ASP.NET configuration instructions](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Configuration)
- [Integration with CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration-section-ckfinder-2)